# Angular 8 : How to do calculation on observable object's two properties and need to save on another property

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, observable, angular-services

I need to show sum of two properties of an observable data. here is my code Please advice me how to fix it.

**Typescript class**

```
export class Amount {
Amount1: number;
Amount2: number;
Total:number;
}
```

**In typescript service:**

I have declared the observable object

```
export class AmountService {    
 public newmessageService = new BehaviorSubject(new Amount());    
  public Model = this.newmessageService.asObservable();     
}
```

**In Component Class:**

subscribed that observable Model in calcuation component

```
export class Calculation implements OnInit {    
Model$:Amount;     
  ngOnInit() {    
    this.service.Model.subscribe(temp => this.Model$ = temp)
  }
}
```

**In component view :**

In the view, Amount1 and Amount2 property are declared for inputs and total is displayed.

```
  <form name="calculationform">

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">    
    <mat-label>Amount1</mat-label>    
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="Model$.Amount1" name="Amount1">    
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">    
    <mat-label>Amount2</mat-label>    
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="Model$.Amount2" name="Amount2">    
  </mat-form-field>

      <mat-label>Total:</mat-label>        
      <mat-label>{{Model$.Total}}</mat-label>
</form>
```

I need to show the sum of Amount1 and Amount2 on Total property when ever we change the amount.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
ngDoCheck( ){
   this.service.Model.subscribe(temp => {
      this.Model$ = temp;
      this.Model$.Total = Number(this.Model$.Amount1) + Number(this.Model$.Amount2);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can consider converting `Total` property to getter.

```js
export class Amount {
  Amount1: number;
  Amount2: number;
  get Total():number {
    return this.Amount1 + this.Amount2;
  };
}
```